# Is French language compulsory for Quebec Skilled Visa?

Tags: visa, canada, pr, language

There is a [Quebec-Selected Skilled Visa](https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/immigrate-canada/quebec-skilled-workers.html) that enables Permanent Residence of Canada and staying in Quebec. The province has its own [rules](http://www.immigration-quebec.gouv.qc.ca/publications/en/divers/GRI_SelectionProgReg_TravQualif2018-EN.pdf) of selection criteria. In those rules, there is a requirement of knowing French and English language. I am confused if there is even any minimum requirement of French or this visa is completely point-based; thereby having knowledge of English suffice if other factors scores the cut-off.

I googled as well, and there are results that says French being compulsory while others saying, not compulsory.  [image]

Answer (score 3):

In order to be qualified for QSW you need French language proficiency.
Although It is not compulsory, you wouldn’t be able to obtain required scores for QSW without having a French language certificate.

If I recall correctly, you would need B2 in both speaking and listening (each has 5 score).

Check Quebec website to see how they score the applicants [here](https://www.immigration-quebec.gouv.qc.ca/en/immigrate-settle/permanent-workers/requirements-programs/index.html).

Quebec immigration streams have been subject to massive changes recently, so Internet websites are not reliable sources and could be old and inaccurate. I strongly recommend to check everything with their official website (above link)